# Bash: Extracting parts of a line and rewriting them?

Tags: bash, string-matching

I have a line (which is part of a list of more of the same) that looks something like:

```
au123456.us.something.net/789/net/Wonderful
```

... and so on.

I'd like to extract the 6 digits in the `auXXXXXX` part, and then also grab everything after the `/`, so I'm able to re-write the line to become:

```
cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com/789/net/Wonderful
```

Is this possible? I'm at a loss with the substitution requirement and the regex... :facepalm:

I was using:

```
echo "au123456.us.something.net/789/net/Wonderful" | sed 's/au/cdn/g;s/us.something.net/au.somewhereelse.com/g'
```

But it's not robust enough for instances like: `au123456.us.something.net/789/net/CaultonHex` for example. The output becomes:

cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com/789/net/C**cdn**ltonHex

Comment: So remove `g` flag if you don't want to do it globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to match globally, don't use `g` flag. `g` flag makes it replace all occurrences, without the `g` flag only the first occurrence is replaced.

```
$ printf "%s\n" au123456.us.something.net/789/net/Wonderful au123456.us.something.net/789/net/CaultonHex  | sed 's/au/cdn/; s/us.something.net/au.somewhereelse.com/'
cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com/789/net/Wonderful
cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com/789/net/CaultonHex
```

Note that in regex `us.something.net` the dot `.` represents *any* character.

```
$ echo au123456.us%something,net/789/net/Wonderful | sed 's/au/cdn/; s/us.something.net/au.somewhereelse.com/'
cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com/789/net/Wonderful
```

Escape the dot with `\.` to match only a dot:

```
sed 's/au/cdn/; s/us\.something\.net/au.somewhereelse.com/'
```

I would personally prefer to match the pattern explicitly, along:

```
$ printf "%s\n" au123456.us.something.net/789/net/Wonderful au123456.us.something.net/789/net/CaultonHex  | sed 's@au\([0-9]\{6\}\)\.us\.something\.net/@cdn\1.au.somewhereelse.com@'
cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com789/net/Wonderful
cdn123456.au.somewhereelse.com789/net/CaultonHex
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `sed 's@au\([0-9]\{6\}\)\.us\.something\.net/@cdn\1.au.somewhereelse.com/@'`